# prevent to open multiple instances of a PWA of a PWA in windows

Tags: windows-10, progressive-web-apps

I deveoped my first PWA to test the worker stuff, notification, instllation update on the different plattforms.

on windows I can open the PWA multiple times, is there an option to prevent this?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I'm working a long time with the PWA technic. It's a quite new feature to add a webapp to the desktop. Maybe future versions will prevent this automatically.

Comment: thanks you, I thought I was too stupid to find the answer, hopefully they will add this feature.